# Where is the secret list of field types kept?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, column

I was trying to update a property on an existing SharePoint site column using the REST API.

I found some tutorials like [this Stack exchange post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/273589/27208) or [this blog](https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/update-field-from-list-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api).

They both have a **__metadata** property for the type -- **SP.Field** and **SP.FieldText** respectively.

```
{"__metadata":{
  "type":"????"
},
'RichText':true }
```

I tried those but received a message that the *property RichText doesn't exist on the type*. Looking at the information I could see about the column it is a **Note** type, so I tried some variations on **SP.Note** and **SP.FieldNote** but no dice.

I wasn't able to google on it because the words *__metadata* and *type* have so many other meanings that didn't lead anywhere.

Eventually I worked out **SP.FieldMultiLineText** is the required magic sauce in this specific case.

Is there some place I can find a listing of what all these magic terms for the different column types are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These field types are the objects under `SP` namespace. Few types I know are:

```
SP.FieldCalculated
SP.FieldChoice
SP.FieldCurrency
SP.FieldDateTime
SP.FieldLookup
SP.FieldMultiChoice
SP.FieldMultiLineText
SP.FieldNumber
SP.FieldText
SP.FieldUrl
SP.FieldUser
```

You can find these at Microsoft documentation: [SP namespace (sp.js)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246996(v=office.15))

---

Also, check this documentation which is really helpful when working with field using SharePoint REST API:

[Fields REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182(v=office.15))